# How to enable Highcharts marker clipping

Tags: highcharts, marker, clipping, clip

In version 2.5.5 markers was automatically clipped by x-axis, in version 3.0.2 they don't.

->  jsfiddle.net/7c8am/2/ - version 2.5.5. markers clipped

->  jsfiddle.net/vzv3X/2/ - last version, markers not clipped

Are there any options to enable clipping back?

Comment: Sorry for inconvinient links, but i see no point in bringing code from jsfiddle to here just to satify awkward stackoveflow requirements..

Comment: Please take look at the thread: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1128

Comment: Thanx, so that was actually bug. Probably need to apply my own clipping on this markers, thanx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed following in highcharts source file (line 13503, ver. 3.0.2):

```
       if (group && this.options.clip !== false) {
            group.clip(chart.clipRect);
            this.markerGroup.clip(); // no clip
        }
```

to

```
        if (group && this.options.clip !== false) {
            group.clip(chart.clipRect);
            this.markerGroup.clip(chart.clipRect);
        }
```